# how to create common html template and reuse it in multiple embedded user task forms in camunda

Tags: html, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have a use case where i need to show values of some process variables on multiple user task forms. Currently i have to write same html in all forms.

Is there a way to extract common part of user task forms to a common html template and then reuse it multiple embedded forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If the UI is identical you can use the same form key on multiple user tasks.

b) If you only want to reuse part of a UI, then you need to leverage the
template/component model of the UI framework you have chosen.

If you are using the new Camunda Forms, then current you only have option a).